# Select2 val does not work for integer value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

[See in the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahdi_negahi/b1c77jjs/)

I' m using JQuery select2 like the following

**HTML**

```
  <select style="width:150px" id="lang" multiple  >
   <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="11">3</option>
 </select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#lang').select2({
        placeholder: 'please type'}   
    );
});
```

my problem is: I want to select an item programmatically

I use following code:

```
    $("#lang").select2('val','11');
```

but the above code select the first item not the last one.

Comment: if I want select multiple item what should I do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe...

```
$(element).select2();
```

...*initializes* Select2, rather than making a selection.

What you're probably looking for is something like this:

```
$("#lang").val("11").trigger("change");
```

If you want to select multiple values, you can use a string array, like so:

```
//Select 11, 12, 13
$("#lang").val(["11", "12", "13"]).trigger("change");
```

---

For more information, check out the [Select2 Examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) documentation.